# Data Retrieval from one to many. Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, one-to-many, information-retrieval

I'm trying to retrieve data from one to many table. But it's not working.There are two models: vehicles and image. A vehicle can have multiple image but an image can have only one vehicle. It is showing undefined variable:image My models are:

```
//Image:
class Image extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['title','filepath'];

    public function vehicles(){

        return $this->belongsTo('App\vehicles');
    }
}

//Vehicle:
class vehicles extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = ['vname','lotno','engine','mileage','kilometers','features','price','negotiable','vcondition','used','manufacture_year','description','Company_cid','Sellers_sid','Vehicle_Type_id'];

    public function Image(){
      return $this->hasMany('App\Image');
    }
}

//Controller:
public function index()
    {
        $vehicle_type=vehicle_types::where('type','Bike')->get()->first();

        $id=$vehicle_type->id;

        $vehicles=vehicles::where('Vehicle_Type_id',$id)->get();

        return view('Bike.index',compact('vehicles'));
    }
```

View:

```
@foreach($vehicles as $vehicles)
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <!-- Product -->
                <div class="shop-item">
                    <!-- Product Image -->
                            <div class="image">
                                <a href="page-product-details.html"><img src="{{ asset("images/$vehicles->$image->title") }}" alt="{{ $vehicles->$image->title }}" ></a>
                            </div>
                    <!-- Product Title -->
                            <div class="title">
                                <h2><a href="page-product-details.html">{{$vehicles->vname}}</a></h2>
                                <h3><a href="page-product-details.html">{{$vehicles->lotno}}</a></h3>
                           </div>
@endforeach
```

I dont know what am i doing wrong. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make model name singular: Vehicle, Image

Vehicle hasMany images

```
  public function images(){
      return $this->hasMany('App\Image');
    }
```

Image belongsTo a Vehicle:

```
public function vehicle(){

        return $this->belongsTo('App\vehicle');
    }
```

And in `index()` method of the controller:

```
$vehicles=Vehicle::where('Vehicle_Type_id',$id)->get();
```

will give you a collection.

And, in the view:

```
@foreach($vehicles as $vehicle)
   @foreach($vehicle->images as $image)
     <a href="page-product-details.html"><img src="{{ asset("images/$image->title") }}" alt="{{ $image->title }}" ></a>
   @endforeach
   <h2><a href="page-product-details.html">{{$vehicle->vname}}</a></h2>
   <h3><a href="page-product-details.html">{{$vehicle->lotno}}</a></h3>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your for loop is wrong, it will be as

```
@foreach($vehicles as $vehicle)
```

and then, access images like

```
$vehicle->Image
```

it will return collection object, as one vehicle has multiple images.
Then in the loop of $vehicle->Image, you can access the Image properties.